# Target specific id and make that specific div editable with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am a beginner with javascript and I am having an issue making a specific div editable upon a button click. Currently I can edit the div but it also makes all divs on the page editable. My code  can be seen below. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
    <form id="contact" action="" method="post">
        <h3>Event Information</h3>
        <div>
            <fieldset>
                <div id="textarea" type="text" name="textarea" required readonly tabindex="5" required><p class="font">{{ userEvent.description }}</p></div>
            </fieldset>
            <input name="Edit" type="button" value="Edit">
        </div>
    </form>
```

{% block scripts %}

```
$('input').click(function(){
    var $div=$('div'), isEditable=$div.is('.editable');
    $('div').prop('contenteditable',!isEditable).toggleClass('editable')
})


$('input[name="Edit"]').click(function(){
    $(this)
    .val(function(i,v){
        return v === 'Edit' ? 'Save' : 'Edit';
    })
    .prev('textarea[required]')
    .prop('readonly',function(i,r){
        return !r;
    });
});
```

{% endblock %}

Comment: Hey, if my answer helped, can you please accept it?

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to select a div with an id, using `getElementById()` would do it.

`var x = document.getElementById('insert div id here');`

You do not need to use a variable, and if you don't want to then:

`document.getElementById('divId').innerHTML = 'hi';

replace `innerHTML = 'hi'` with whatever code you need. If you want a better explanation, click [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementbyid.asp).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can use :nth-child() Selector to select a specific 'div' you want to modify.

If you want to use pure JS, use document.querySelectorAll('div') and get access to a specific div using square brackets.

Ex -

```
var divs = document.querySelectorAll('div');
var second = divs[1];
```

Thanks

Comment: is it possible to call a specific id? I appreciate the help

Answer (score 0):

You can do this all in one go, but you need to

1. Navigate up to the `fieldset` and then to the `div` within
2. Get your condition right for adding/removing the `contentEditable` prop.

```js
$('input[name="Edit"]').click(function(){
    $(this)
    .val(function(i,v){
        return v === 'Edit' ? 'Save' : 'Edit';
    })
    .prev('fieldset')
    .children("div")
    .prop('contentEditable',function(i,r){
        return r == "inherit" ? true : "inherit";
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="contact" action="" method="post">
    <h3>Event Information</h3>
    <div>
        <fieldset>
            <div id="textarea" type="text" name="textarea" required readonly tabindex="5" required ><p class="font">{{ userEvent.description }}</p></div>
        </fieldset>
        <input name="Edit" type="button" value="Edit">
    </div>
</form>
```